# Celery not configuring different queues

Tags: django, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I've installed celery 4.1.1 and setup queues and routes but the worker accepts data only via name 'celery'.

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = "default"
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = "default"
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = "direct"

CELERY_QUEUES = {
    'default': {
        "exchange": "default",
        "binding_key": "default"
    },
    'recon_queue': {
        "exchange": "recon_queue",
        "routing_key": "recon_queue"
    }
}

CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'reconciliation.tasks.sync_bag': {'queue': 'default'},
    'common.consumer.kafka_consumer': {'queue': 'recon_queue'}

}

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "kafka_consumer": {
        'task': 'kafka_consumer',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/01'),
    },
}
```

The periodic task is run via celery beat.
This command works fine - celery -A inferno worker -l info -Q celery -c1
This worker does all the tasks itself.

But these commands dont have any effect
celery -A inferno worker -l info -Q default -c1
celery -A inferno worker -l info -Q recon_queue -c1

Comment: Could it be the name? ie. in you CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE the task name is "kafka_consumer" but in CELERY_ROUTES you define the recon_queue for the task name "common.consumer.kafka_consumer"?

Comment: changed the name 'recon_queue' to 'kafka_consumer' everywhere but no effect